# Dynamic object doesn't load on scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a car garage game. I make the car selection script to work with dynamics GameObjects cars, loaded as Objects from resources. I also want to load dynamically the wheels because I have a set of 40 wheels.

So when the game starts, the first car is initialized in the scene and the script wheels generate the wheels appending them on the car wheels containers. After changing the car, I apply the same logic, but the wheels don't initiate anymore.

Here is my garage logic. Can anyone help, please?

```
public class GarageController : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject m_CarsCollectionHolder;
private Object[] cars = null;
private Object[] wheels = null;
private GameObject current_car = null;
private GameObject current_wheel_FL, current_wheel_FR, current_wheel_RL, current_wheel_RR;
private GameObject FL, FR, RL, RR;
private int current_car_id = 0;
private int current_wheels_id = 0;

void Start () {
    int first_time_init = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("first_time_init");
    if(first_time_init == 0)
    {
        this.FirstTimeInit();
    }

    this.LoadWheels();
    //Car load last;
    this.CarInit();
}

/*
 * First time game open init
 */
private void FirstTimeInit()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("first_time_init", 1);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selected_car_id", 0);
}

/*
 * Car init when game object ( based on last car selection and customizations )
 */
private void CarInit()
{
    this.current_car_id = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selected_car_id");
    this.cars = Resources.LoadAll("cars", typeof(GameObject));
    this.SetCar(this.current_car_id);
}


/*
 * Car selection controllers
 */
public void NextCar()
{
    if(this.current_car_id + 1 < cars.Length)
    {
        this.current_car_id++;
    }
    else
    {
        this.current_car_id = 0;
    }
    this.SetCar(this.current_car_id);
}

public void PreviousCar()
{
    if (this.current_car_id - 1  >= 0)
    {
        this.current_car_id--;
    }
    else
    {
        this.current_car_id = cars.Length - 1;
    }
    this.SetCar(this.current_car_id);
} 


private void SetCar(int car_id)
{
    Destroy(this.current_car);
    this.current_car = Instantiate(cars[car_id]) as GameObject;
    this.current_car.transform.SetParent(m_CarsCollectionHolder.transform, false);

    // Get current wheels containers
    this.current_wheel_FL = GameObject.Find("FL");
    this.current_wheel_FR = GameObject.Find("FR");
    this.current_wheel_RL = GameObject.Find("RL");
    this.current_wheel_RR = GameObject.Find("RR");

    //Set history wheels
    this.current_wheels_id = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("selected_wheels_for_car_" + car_id);
    this.ChangeWheels(current_wheels_id);

    SetCurrentCarId(car_id);
}

private void SetCurrentCarId(int car_id)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("selected_car_id", car_id);
}


// Wheels controller
private void LoadWheels()
{
    this.wheels = Resources.LoadAll("wheels", typeof(GameObject));
}

private void ChangeWheels(int current_wheels_id)
{
    //Destroy old wheels
    Destroy(this.FL);
    Destroy(this.FR);
    Destroy(this.RL);
    Destroy(this.RR);

    //Init wheels
    this.FL = Instantiate(this.wheels[current_wheels_id]) as GameObject;
    this.FR = Instantiate(this.wheels[current_wheels_id]) as GameObject;
    this.RL = Instantiate(this.wheels[current_wheels_id]) as GameObject;
    this.RR = Instantiate(this.wheels[current_wheels_id]) as GameObject;

    //Move wheels in their containers, and rotate
    this.FL.transform.SetParent(current_wheel_FL.transform, false);
    this.FR.transform.SetParent(current_wheel_FR.transform, false);
    this.FR.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);
    this.RL.transform.SetParent(current_wheel_RL.transform, false);
    this.RR.transform.SetParent(current_wheel_RR.transform, false);
    this.RR.transform.Rotate(0, 180, 0);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't instantiate or you can't set their parent to the appropriate place?
I think when you destroy the object, for example "FL", you lose the reference you hold in "current_wheel_FL" so you can't use its "transform" to set it as a parent.